# Use NSPredicate to filter multiple results and select the one that is visible in XCUITest?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Would it be possible to use NSPredicate to filter multiple results and select the one that is visible?

This line of code will return multiple results:

`app.otherElements.containing(.staticText, identifier:"THIS TEXT")`

I would like to filter out and select that one that is visible. The reason why I am doing this is to I'd like to skip over the cells. This is the code that is generated after using the recorder:

```
let collectionViewsQuery = app.collectionViews
collectionViewsQuery.cells.collectionViews.cells.collectionViews.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 10).otherElements.containing(.staticText, identifier:"THIS TEXT").children(matching: .image).element.tap()
```

I'm currently trying to simply it by skipping the index specification but the staticText identifier returns multiple results. How do I filter it out?